# can't get the logic to restart looping

Tags: php, logic

I have 15 databases 1,2,3,4, ... 15
and I have the variable $i default at 1 and each time the $i count gets to 3, $i restarts the looping from 1 again until 3 and it will stop until value from database is done counting.

```
$detailPsycho = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `psycho` WHERE `flag` = 2 ") or die(mysql_error());
        while($detail = mysql_fetch_array($detailPsycho)){

    for($i = 1;$i<=3;$i++){ 
        echo $detail['sequence']."&".$i." <br>";
    }
        }
```

and run over like this :/

> ```
> 1&1 
> 1&2 
> 1&3 
> 2&1 
> 2&2 
> 2&3
> ```

Comment: What exactly isn't working as you're expecting?

Comment: i think it will go like 1&1, 2&2, 3&3, 4&1, 5&2, and so on. LoL

Comment: You could take out the for loop inside the while, and initialize $i to 0, and make the echo ($i%3+1) and increment $i in the while loop.

Comment: Why would it do that? You're looping over each result 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to do a loop (`for{}`) in a loop (`while{}`) which is a complicated way of doing something trivial. This is the "while+for" result :

```
$detailPsycho = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `psycho` WHERE `flag` = 2 ") or die(mysql_error());

i = (int) 1;
while($detail = mysql_fetch_array($detailPsycho)) {

    echo $detail['sequence']."&".$i." <br>";
    $i++;
    if ($i > 3) $i = 1;
}
```